# How can I write correct reasons for custom flags?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I accessed my list of flags and I observed that 8/150 have been declined.

I suppose that I did something wrong, but I don't know what. Can you explain this to me? What should I emphasize in that description? Or are those posts ok (should not be flagged)?

E.g.: URL + my explanation

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379348/multiple-text-box-with-addition-is-not-working

   > Its quality is very low. It doesn't include details, only a link.
2. [google map api v3 search box with dragable marker and input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353044/google-map-api-v3-search-box-with-dragable-marker-and-input-box)

   > It has a very low quality: no code, no details ...
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341392/how-to-get-list-of-dates-by-month-year-and-week-no-in-java

   > It doesn't contain details about his attempt to solve this problem. It also has a wrong format.

Answer (score 13):

The following was provided in the decline reason for at least one of those:

> Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderator attention.

You're using custom moderator flags to demand our immediate attention to questions you want to be closed. Closing questions can and should largely be done by the community, without requiring moderator intervention.

If you believe such questions should be closed, and they aren't an immediate problem (spam, trolling, etc.), I recommend instead using standard close flags or voting to close (if you have sufficient reputation). Close flags will bring these questions to the attention of the community, and at least one of those was closed by the community in the natural course of things.

We typically only need to step in when the community cannot handle something themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that some of posts are for community and the other posts are for moderators (I don't have enough reputation to review close votes and this is why I didn't observe that difference). I think that I'll just skip the posts in some cases, because sometimes those existing flags are not enough to describe the problem.

Comment: @goodMan all three examples fit existing flags perfectly. You can flag to close questions, and flag answers, based on low quality, link only and so on. Save Other for special cases - I have ten times your flags and don't think I've raised more than 10 Other flags.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I couldn't see that "perfectly", but English is not my mother language, so I can be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use NAA
2. Use Close => Too Broad
3. Use Close => Unclear what you're asking

Custom-reason flags should only be used **absolutely necessary**. Since custom-reason flags can't be handled by the vast majority of users as standard reason flags can, they add to the backlog of moderator flags, and often take *longer* to be processed.